# Is ":::" an operator?

Tags: r, operator-keyword

I am looking through some R Code. Some environments are defined as

```
"PackageName":::."EnvironmentName"
```

What I don't get is what exactly ::: and . are for? Is using ::: just a convention or some kind of scoping operator? Futhermore, what does the "." stand for?

Thx

Comment: `?':::'` the dot is just part of the variable name

Comment: thx. I tried help(:::), guess I have a lot to learn. so basically starting the environment by a "." is a convention?

Comment: See page 42 in R inferno.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:::` is an operator for accessing internal variables in a package namespace. 
For example

```
utils:::.addFunctionInfo
```

accesses the function `.addFunctionInfo` from the `utils` package. `:::` is an operator and the underlying function is `` `:::`(pkg, name) ``. It can be called with the arguments `"utils"`, `".addFunctionInfo"`:

```
> `:::`("utils", ".addFunctionInfo")
function (...) 
{
    dots <- list(...)
    for (nm in names(dots)) .FunArgEnv[[nm]] <- dots[[nm]]
}
<bytecode: 0x000000002e4240d0>
<environment: namespace:utils>
```

When the R parser sees `utils:::.addFunctionInfo` it interpretes it as `` `:::`("utils", ".addFunctionInfo") ``
You can get help on the operator by using

```
?`:::`
```

The dot in this case is just part of the variable name. In unix it is often used to denote a hidden file.